# Best way to communicate between Siblings components in Blazor Assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have 3 components on a blazor page
Component Client, ClientInfo and ClientList

the CLIENT is the father of both ClientInfo and ClientList
ClientInfo and ClientList are Siblings

I want in the clientList when user click on the EDIT button then the client entity send to the ClientInfo

I can pass parameters between parent and child but I want to know what is the best way to do it?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired design should be as follows:

A parent: component named `ClientList` which displays a list (selected fields only) of client objects in a `tabular` form ( datagrid ).

A child: component named `ClientInfo` which displays the client info object in a `form` form for a selected client, when the `Edit` button is clicked. You may pass the complete client info object or the id of the client to the created `ClientInfo` component. After the user has edited the client info form, and pressed the "Save" button, you should pass back the updated object to the parent component, that is, to the `ClientList` component for further processing, as for instance, saving the newly edited data to a data store, etc. This sending and getting procedure between a parent component and its child is named Two-way Component data-binding, and should be made according to the following pattern:

`@bind-Value="ClientInfoObject"` for the the parameter property Value defined in the child component.

You also need to define the mechanism to return the edited client info object to the parent component by defining a call back parameter property:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<ClientInfoObject> ValueChanged {get; set;}
```

And now you can call the ValueChanged 'delegate' from your code to pass back the edited client info object to the parent component. This can be done form a "Save" method.

Note: Another two ways to implement the above is to use cascading parameters and services. Search my answers in stackoverflow. Neither is recommended here, and you should do it as I describe above.

Note also that you may display your `ClientInfo` component in-line; that is, immediately below the row of the selected client in the `ClientList`